# With Linux and gcc, are basic characters encoded as in ASCII?

Tags: linux, gcc, character-encoding

On my Linux system and with the gcc version I am using, if I print the numerical encoding of any Basic Latin or whitespace character, it turns out that they have the ASCII encoding, as specified for example in http://www.asciitable.com/ - all the following C expressions are true:

```
'\t' == 9
'\n' == 10
' ' == 32
'!' == 33
'"' == 34
```

(...)

```
'~' == 126
```

I know the above does not always have to be true, for any system, as it is not part of the C standard.

Is it true for any current Linux distribution and using gcc?

Comment: Well, yes it is wide, that's why I am asking it.  If this was a question about the platform that I have, it would be easy to check and I would not be asking.  Perhaps you can point me to some source documentation where I can get the answer from.  I am not even sure whether Linux or gcc or both, have influence over the encoding; in other words, my question could possibly be incorrectly posed.  If I knew, I would have posed it differently or not at all.

Comment: @Robert Why are you asking what I am asking?  I asked the question as stated, nothing less, nothing more.  I know the C standard, that's not what the question is about.  I am not asking about any "data my code works with", and I am not asking about any non-basic characters.  I am not sure why you thought I did...

Comment: Well, the problem is, I did spend a good deal of time composing the question, to be the clearest I can.  My complaining and frustration comes from the fact that I perceive people don't spend time reading it carefully. If you can tell me which part is not clear I will appreciate.  Thank you.

Comment: Is it better now?  Not for me, but maybe it is more understandable for you.

Comment: Are you asking that all C programs on Linux will be in ASCII, as opposed to C programs on some mainframe which could be in e.g., EBCDIC? That would seem more like a general OS setting to me than anything C or compiler specific. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161708/can-centos-be-set-to-pure-ebcdic

Comment: With so many character sets having encodings that map the same characters to the same values, you can't conclude that you are seeing ASCII. gcc supports -fexec-charset so you could conclude that it is used or at least tested with different values.

Comment: @TomBlodget hold on - I am looking at `-fexec-charset` option, it says, the default is UTF-8, and you know, UTF-8 is ASCII-compatible, so that would mean, if I just compile my program with gcc and don't use this option, so then by default, all the expressions in my question will be true.  So in other words, even though this is not in the C standard, for the gcc implementation of C, the expressions are true.  Am I getting this right?